# Delete common values from string variables using shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables

I want to delete duplicate values from a string/s. (I am NOT looking for a common solution that suits for both the examples.)

Example 1:

```
var1="foo bar foo1 foo2 foo bar"
```

Expected output:

```
var1="foo1 foo2"
```

Example 2:

```
var1="foo bar foo1 foo2"
var2="foo bar"
```

Expected output:

```
var1="foo1 foo2"
```

I had tried the following
echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq

This gives me the values foo and bar along with foo1 and bar1

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your Q to include your best attempt to solve your problem (including your current output). We'll help you fix about anything, but we won't write it for you. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank @shellter, edited the question now

Answer (score 1):

For example 1, you can use the `-u` option of sort, which keeps unique elements.

```sh
$ var1="foo bar foo1 foo2 foo   bar"
$ var1_u="$(echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u)"
$ echo $var1_u
bar foo foo1 foo2
```

Omitting to use quotes when echoing `$var1` makes sure that values are separated by a single space. Using this followed by a `tr ' ' '\n'` is a widely-used pattern if you want to process elements later with a program using lines as inputs (e.g. `sort`, `grep`, ...).

For example 2, you can use `grep -v` (reverse matching: prints line if value not matched) to filter elements from `$var1` that are in `$var2`.

```sh
$ var1="foo bar foo1 foo2" var2="foo bar"
$ var1_u="$(echo $var1 | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v "^\($(echo $var2 | sed 's/ /\\|/g')\)$")"
$ echo $var1_u
foo1 foo2
```

Ideally, you should add escaping before the sed to ensure the regex is not broken, but if you do not plan to include any special characters in `$var2`, you should be fine.

Comment: thank you @Anis Ladram. The solution for example 2 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For example1, please try:

```
var1="foo bar foo1 foo2 foo bar"
declare -A seen         # count the occurrences of the words in var1
declare -a result

for i in $var1; do
    (( seen[$i]++ ))    # increment the counter of the word
done

for i in "${!seen[@]}"; do
    if (( ${seen[$i]} == 1 )); then
                        # if the word occurs just once
        result+=($i)    # then append the word to the result
    fi
done
echo "${result[*]}"
```

Output:

```
foo1 foo2
```

As of the example2:

```
var1="foo bar foo1 foo2"
var2="foo bar"
declare -A seen         # count the occurrences of the words in var2
declare -a result

for i in $var2; do
    (( seen[$i]++ ))
done

for i in $var1; do
    if ! (( ${seen[$i]} )); then
                        # if not found in var2 list
        result+=($i)    # then append the word to the result
    fi
done
echo "${result[*]}"
```

Output:

```
foo1 foo2
```